# A way around the deprecation of AppInvite in Unity

Tags: unity, facebook

I was using [FB.Mobile.AppInvite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Mobile.AppInvite), but according to [the Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites), it is deprecated.

So, how could I send an app invite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using firebase : https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/unity

Some people gave the figure 18% of the app invite through facebook (other through wathsapp, etc...)